# Function created in vala showing unexpected syntax error

Tags: vala

[image]

This is how I create a new function so that when a button is clicked, the preferences view should open.

But when I compile it, this is the error displayed.
[image]

https://github.com/Suzie97/epoch, link to the repository on github

What is the syntax error on my code?? Why is this error shown?

Comment: Please try to use code blocks instead of screenshots. It makes the code searchable (and better fit for reading in certain cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code snippet, but you have place it in your `construct` method of your class. In your `Epoch.MainWindow` calss in [src/MainWindow.vala](https://github.com/Suzie97/epoch/blob/main/src/MainWindow.vala) you want to method out of the scope of `construct` and in to the scope of `MainWindow`.